# See available methods of ActiveX object

Tags: vba, activex, intellisense

I can create `ActiveX` object using interface of custom app:

```
Dim CustomObject As Object
Set CustomObject = CreateObject("CustomApp.CustomOleInterface")
```

But I don't know API of this interface. Can I see available methods for `CustomObject`? Or can I dump object to file for viewing it in HEX-redactor?

Comment: Late-bound libaries don't expose their members. Bind it early (add a refences in vba-ide) and look at Object-Browser. Or read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262134/how-can-i-browse-the-classes-and-methods-of-an-activex-dll (first hit on your title in search engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use intellisense with late binding. You would have to add the DLL/TLB file to the project references to use early binding.

In the VB Editor:

Go to **Tools >> References**

A dialog will appear where you can select the file using the checkbox next to its name. It will be in the list if it is registered in your system. If it is not, you would have to use the Browse button and locate it yourself.

Comment: It looks like something that can help. The only thing I don't know where the desired DLL/TLB file. No one of files from the application folder no approached. Can you suggest where it might be located?

Comment: Check`%windir%/system32`for x64 libs and `%windir%/syswow64`for x86 libs.